# Even order group, contains element of order 2

Tags: group-theory

Show every finite group of even order contains an element of order 2.

I have tried using Lagrange's theorem, but I am unsure if this is the right path.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem does not tell you that if $n|N$, then there is an element of order $n$, where $|G| = N$. (ie. there is no element of order $6$ in $A_4$)

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**:

Every element of a group has an inverse.  So given such a group $G$, try pairing every element with its inverse.  What happens?  What must therefore be the case?

---

Side-note:  This is a special case of [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29).